# Error in ASIHTTP class

Tags: iphone

i am using ASIHTTP class.I am using non-arc code structure.And also using libASILib.a instead of implementation file.
I am getting error:`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIFormDataRequest", referenced from:`
I am able to run in device but not able to run in simulator.Please help me.Thanking you in advance...

Comment: Are you tied [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786285/error-in-asiformdatarequest-objc-class-asiformdatarequest-referenced-from) solutions?

Comment: @CAMOBAP : hey i am using libASILib.a instead of .m files.

Comment: the library hasn't been built for i386. You need to build the .a file as a fat binary that includes object files for i386 and armv

Comment: @MaxMacLeod : so should i replace it by .m files?

Comment: ideally, ditch AsiHttp. It's old and it's no longer supported. Move to AFNetworking.

Comment: oh, and read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839981/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-i386